# How to load and display multiple images in series while moving the slider?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm creating a function in my image viewer in Qt using c++ where multiple images can be loaded and displayed in series while moving the slider. Any ideas or code references I can refer to? Thank you.

```
    void MainWindow::on_btn_image_clicked()
    {
        qDebug()<<"clicked.....";
        QStringList filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this, tr("Browse Image"), "", tr("Images(*.png *.jpg *.bmp *.gif)"));

        if (!filename.isEmpty())
        {
            for(int i=0; i<filename.length(); i++)
            {
                QString str = filename.at(i) ;
                qDebug()<<"str========>>>>>"<<str;

                QImage image1(str);

                QByteArray bytes;
                QBuffer buffer(&bytes);
                buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
                image1.save(&buffer,"");
                buffer.close();

                unsigned char *data_image = (unsigned char *)malloc(bytes.size());
                memcpy(data_image, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(bytes.data()), (unsigned int)bytes.size());



                auto sigMap = new QSignalMapper(this);

                horizontalSlider[i] = new QSlider(this);
                connect(horizontalSlider[i], SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), sigMap, SLOT(map()));

                sigMap->setMapping(horizontalSlider[i], i);

                connect(sigMap, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(slider_x(int)));


                int h=image1.height();
                int w=image1.width();

                QImage image2(str);
                image2= QImage(data_image, h, w, QImage::Format_Indexed8);

                if (image2.height()>=image2.width())
                {
                     image = image2.scaledToHeight(ui->graphicsView->height(), Qt::SmoothTransformation);
                }

                else
                {
                     image = image2.scaledToWidth(ui->graphicsView->width(), Qt::SmoothTransformation);
                }

                item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap::fromImage(image));

                scene[i] = new QGraphicsScene(this);
                ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene[i]);
                scene[i]->addItem(item);

            }
        }

     }

    void MainWindow::slider_x(int i)
    {
        int value = horizontalSlider[i]->value();
    }
```

I'm trying to convert the images into byte arrays and auto connect the arrays to the slider. Is there any problem with the concept or the codes?

Comment: Do you want to have something like a slideshow or just put the image side by side?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure whether "in series" is the appropriate word. The result I want is actually when moving the slider one step, the first image will be replaced by the second image and same concept goes on until the last image is viewed. And it is reversible.

Comment: Another thing, is it more appropriate to change the title to "...in parallel..."?

Comment: *Of course* it is possible to cause the movement of a slider to show a different image. But, without seeing a [mcve] of your code it is impossible to tell you what you did wrong. And asking for links to external resources etc is *explicitly* off topic. This is also *not* a tutorial site. And we don't write code for you. Show us what you've tried and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Sorry, I'm a new user and I'm still not used to the culture in stack overflow. I have just added my codes. Could help to check? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to load all the images in a layout within a flickable and connect the flickable with a slider. You can choose the layout in a way that the following pictures are loaded off-screen, so you would have a bar of images you can move across your window/screen. However, this can become very ressource-expensive when the amount of pictures get larger. If you're handling lots of images you should load them on demand, and unload them when they're offscreen. But with this method I'm unsure how to handle the items/objects.

Comment: I think my case it's still ok because only 10 images will be loaded. But my problem now is how to connect the slider with the images loaded and display them one by one while moving the slider step by step.

Comment: Did you look into the documentation of QAbstractSlider? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html It should have the functions you need. If i understand your intentions correctly, you could simply read out the slider position after it was moved and load the according image. (Use one of the sliders signals)